# Docker stop/start resets to initial passwords

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've just started using docker by copy-pasting pre-made repos from github.

Here is the scenario and steps:

1. I've passed mysql/shell root password via environment variable -e and these passwords are set as expected inside entry.sh.
2. I then go inside container and reset shell/mysql root password to something different.
3. Now the main issue, each time I do docker stop + start from host, it resets passwords to the initial ones of step1.

Please suggest the changes so it retain the modified step2 passwords even I do docker start/stop.

Used [entry.sh](https://github.com/azghanvi/docker-lamp-ssh-custom/blob/main/entry.sh) and [dockerfile](https://github.com/azghanvi/docker-lamp-ssh-custom/blob/main/Dockerfile) scripts can be checked from this github repo.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can persist the change by binding mysql config and data to external path by using `--volume` option when starting the container. Check this article https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-docker-container

Comment: Thanks but it does not help. Volume don't help in stop resetting shell root password. May be there is something missing in using entry.sh & dockerfile.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right about the entry.sh. In that case, we can try to edit it a bit to avoid the password update on `docker start`. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that the `entry.sh` will always update the root password with `$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` on `docker start`. So assuming we already persist the `/var/lib/mysql` in the host, we can edit the `entry.sh` a bit to only update the password when `/var/lib/mysql` doesn't exists:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start apache
echo "Starting httpd"
httpd
echo "Done httpd"


# check if mysql data directory is nuked
# if so, install the db
echo "Checking /var/lib/mysql folder"
if [ ! -f /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 ]; then 
    echo "Installing db"
    mariadb-install-db --user=mysql --ldata=/var/lib/mysql > /dev/null
    echo "Installed"

    # from mysql official docker repo
    if [ -z "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -a -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
                echo >&2 'error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified '
                echo >&2 '  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD'
                exit 1
    fi

    # random password
    if [ ! -z "$MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
        echo "Using random password"
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="$(pwgen -1 32)"
        echo "GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
        echo "Done"
    fi

    tfile=`mktemp`
    if [ ! -f "$tfile" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    cat << EOF > $tfile
        USE mysql;
        DELETE FROM user;
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY "$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" WITH GRANT OPTION;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
        UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("") WHERE user='root' AND host='localhost';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF

    echo "Querying user"
    /usr/bin/mysqld --user=root --bootstrap --verbose=0 < $tfile
    rm -f $tfile
    echo "Done query"    


    # setting ssh root password
    if [ -z "$SSH_ROOT_PASSWORD" ]; then
        echo >&2 'You need to specify SSH_ROOT_PASSWORD'
        exit
    fi

    # Set root password to root, format is 'user:password'.
    echo "root:$SSH_ROOT_PASSWORD" | chpasswd
fi;


echo "Generating ssh keys"
if [ ! -f "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key" ]; then
    # generate fresh rsa key
    ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key" ]; then
    # generate fresh dsa key
    ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa
fi

#prepare run dir
if [ ! -d "/var/run/sshd" ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
fi

ssh-keygen -A
/usr/sbin/sshd


# start mysql
# nohup mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --bind-address 0.0.0.0 --user mysql > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo "Starting mariadb database"
exec /usr/bin/mysqld --user=root --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Basically we just move [this block of code](https://github.com/azghanvi/docker-lamp-ssh-custom/blob/main/entry.sh#L44-L77) to the if block above it

Comment: That was really simple, thanks for pointing.